# WebApi Core : Force integer input Parameter to be sent

Tags: c#

I have this below model

```
public class sampleModel
{
    [BindRequired]
    //[Required]
    public int id { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

this below json data, i am sending from postman to webapi

```
{  
    "Name": "Test"
}
```

here I am expecting, webapi to throw an error stating that `Id` is required, but instead it is giving me a success message.
I want to force the `Id` parameter to be posted to webapi, how do I achieve this?

Comment: The required attribute has not worked?

Comment: `//[Required]` - is this part commented like this when you tried the code?

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
public class sampleModel
{
    [Required]
    public int id { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

and in the controller, you check if Model State is Valid.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
     //throw exception or any status code that you want here.
}
```